# How to set different font size for x and y axis using cex.axis

Tags: r, plot

1)I would like to reduce the size of y axis font 2) Y axis label is away from the y axis. How to put y axis label close to the y axis?

Here is my code:-

```
x <-  c(83,20,15.7,9.91,20.5,18.7,23.5,18.67,56,78,12,45,24)
boxplot(x, ylim=c(0,100), cex.lab=1.6, cex.axis = 1.5, cex.main = 2 ,ylab = "Average of marks")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could suppress and then manually add your customized y-axis:

```
boxplot(x, ylim=c(0,100), yaxt="n") 
axis(2, cex.axis=.5, padj=2.5, tck=-.005)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still the y axis label is away from the axis.

Comment: Define "away". You could increase `padj` to, say, `3.5`, and it's even _on_ the axis.

Comment: padj woks with y axis text. Actually, I would like to move the yaxis title.

Comment: Thank you so much!